# tkinter methods .bell() no sound

Tags: python, tkinter, ubuntu-16.04

I tried tkinter `.bell()` method but there was no sound. Below is a simple test code that I had used, it did not yield any bell sound. How to get the bell to work?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame( root )
label = tk.Label( frame , text='Testing w.bell() method')

frame.pack()
label.pack()

label.bell()
frame.bell()
root.bell()

root.mainloop()
```

**Update:**

```
$ xset q | grep bell
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
```

I can't understand why my system does not yield any bell sound despite others stating that they can here the bell sound.

Comment: Are you sure your sound is on? Because all three `.bell()` works on my machine.  Note it sounded just like "one" bell because the three were ran in succession without delay.  Also I believe you need the alert sound set up on your OS... make sure your OS's sound profile is not silent or and have set an alert sound.

Comment: @Idlehands am using Ubuntu 16.04. It's Alert Sound works, I can hear it. But somehow the bell sound can't be heard even though the system speaker and Alert volume are set to maximum.

Answer (score 0):

The `bell` function is audible if you let the system initialize itself. Just try to add a little tempo:

```py
import time
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
label = tk.Label(frame, text='Testing w.bell() method')

frame.pack()
label.pack()

time.sleep(.5)
label.bell()
time.sleep(.5)
frame.bell()
time.sleep(.5)
root.bell()

root.mainloop()
```

See also: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bell.htm

Comment: `$ xset q | grep bell`  returns  `bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration: 100` Can't understand why I can't hear the bell.